# Mathjax not reloading on realtime updates

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, mathjax

Whenever a new answer is posted, the realtime update shows a gray bar and loads it on click.

But, any math syntax used will still look like <sup>`$\rho \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} \right) = -\nabla p + \nabla \cdot\mathbb{T} + \mathbf{f}$`</sup>. Basically, mathjax isn't being reloaded. On the other hand, when a new question is realtime-loaded onto the front page, mathjax in the title *does* load properly, so I'm guessing that it's not [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the next build MathJax will be processed on the load of new answers.

Comment: Don't forget the review section as well!

Comment: @Manishearth can you make a new post for that?

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128068/mathjax-not-loaded-properly-on-review

Comment: This is a bit trivial to post as a bugreport, so I'll just post it here: On the mobile site (when viewed through a desktop browser), even though viewing vote counts is disabled, the cursor becomes `cursor:pointer` on hover, and a tooltip shows up (in contrast with any other _working_ link on the site--these have no hover tooltip/cursor). It also seems to have some event handlers attached. Looks like unnecessary overhead to me... :/

Comment: Any progress on the review section?