# MathJax not loaded properly on review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, mathjax

> Related review loading issue: [Format code as code in the review preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77278/format-code-as-code-in-the-review-preview)

Could you reload MathJax on clicking the `review question` link in the review section? It sort of defeats the "stay on this page and review" purpose of the review section if you have to open the page in a new tab to review it.

It's understandable if half-displayed math is not rendered (second freehand circle in picture), but it really ought to load/fix itself after the "review" link is clicked.

[image]

Note: IMO, this *does* slow down review speed :/

Comment: We're not ignoring this...we just have larger plans here and it'll be addressed as part of that, stay tuned.  Our best engineers (so definitely not me) are on it!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, but it's a viable workaround:

[ChatJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297/24293) is pretty useful in this case--just click the bookmarklet every time you load a page with math in the review section.